MobileScanner camera preview freezes on Android 12
I have implemented the QR code scanning feature in my Flutter app using https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_scanner plugin.
it's working fine on Android 10 devices but I don't know why the camera preview screen for scanning QR freezes on android 12 devices only.
final scanController = MobileScannerController(detectionSpeed: DetectionSpeed.normal,autoStart: true,facing: CameraFacing.front);

MobileScanner(controller: scanController, onDetect: (barcode) {
final String code = barcode.barcodes.first.rawValue ?? '';
if (code.isNotEmpty) {
  scanController.stop();
}});

Since I am new to Flutter app development I cannot solve this camera freeze issue occurring only on Android 12 devices.
I have a Lenovo Tab K10 with Android 12
The camera works fine on the first load but freezes on the second load.
Logs are as below
D/GlobalPenUtil(12733): handleGlobalPenEvent ACTION_UP  isPenView: false
D/GlobalPenUtil(12733):  ViewRootImpl  handleGlobalPenEvent ACTION_UP is not PenView: 
[log] scan qr called
I/BufferQueueConsumer(12733): [](id:31bd0000000c,api:0,p:-1,c:12733) connect: controlledByApp=true
D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore(12733): Storing event with priority=DEFAULT, name=FIREBASE_ML_SDK for destination cct
D/CameraOrientationUtil(12733): getRelativeImageRotation: destRotationDegrees=0, sourceRotationDegrees=270, isOppositeFacing=false, result=270
D/CameraOrientationUtil(12733): getRelativeImageRotation: destRotationDegrees=0, sourceRotationDegrees=270, isOppositeFacing=false, result=270
D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler(12733): Upload for context TransportContext(cct, DEFAULT, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MGNjL2xvZy9iYXRjaD9mb3JtYXQ9anNvbl9wcm90bzNc) is already scheduled. Returning...
D/DynamicRangeResolver(12733): Resolved dynamic range for use case androidx.camera.core.Preview-9e64dbef-b427-42a4-9edc-336238217282 to no compatible HDR dynamic ranges.
D/DynamicRangeResolver(12733): DynamicRange@5ff1420{encoding=UNSPECIFIED, bitDepth=0}
D/DynamicRangeResolver(12733): ->
D/DynamicRangeResolver(12733): DynamicRange@cb3f723{encoding=SDR, bitDepth=8}
D/CameraOrientationUtil(12733): getRelativeImageRotation: destRotationDegrees=0, sourceRotationDegrees=270, isOppositeFacing=false, result=270
D/DeferrableSurface(12733): Surface created[total_surfaces=1, used_surfaces=0](androidx.camera.core.processing.SurfaceEdge$SettableSurface@eed5b25}
D/DeferrableSurface(12733): Surface created[total_surfaces=2, used_surfaces=0](androidx.camera.core.SurfaceRequest$2@d3d84a1}
D/DeferrableSurface(12733): New surface in use[total_surfaces=2, used_surfaces=1](androidx.camera.core.SurfaceRequest$2@d3d84a1}
D/DeferrableSurface(12733): use count+1, useCount=1 androidx.camera.core.SurfaceRequest$2@d3d84a1
D/CameraOrientationUtil(12733): getRelativeImageRotation: destRotationDegrees=0, sourceRotationDegrees=270, isOppositeFacing=false, result=270
I/BufferQueueConsumer(12733): [](id:31bd0000000d,api:0,p:-1,c:12733) connect: controlledByApp=true
D/CameraOrientationUtil(12733): getRelativeImageRotation: destRotationDegrees=0, sourceRotationDegrees=270, isOppositeFacing=false, result=270
I/BufferQueueConsumer(12733): [](id:31bd0000000e,api:0,p:-1,c:12733) connect: controlledByApp=true
D/CameraOrientationUtil(12733): getRelativeImageRotation: destRotationDegrees=0, sourceRotationDegrees=270, isOppositeFacing=false, result=270
D/DeferrableSurface(12733): Surface created[total_surfaces=3, used_surfaces=1](androidx.camera.core.impl.ImmediateSurface@6e17952}
D/Camera2CameraImpl(12733): {Camera@c86a89f[id=1]} Use case androidx.camera.core.Preview-9e64dbef-b427-42a4-9edc-336238217282244191593 ACTIVE
D/UseCaseAttachState(12733): Active and attached use case: [] for camera: 1
D/CameraOrientationUtil(12733): getRelativeImageRotation: destRotationDegrees=0, sourceRotationDegrees=270, isOppositeFacing=false, result=270
D/CameraOrientationUtil(12733): getRelativeImageRotation: destRotationDegrees=0, sourceRotationDegrees=270, isOppositeFacing=false, result=270
D/Camera2CameraImpl(12733): {Camera@c86a89f[id=1]} Use case androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis-4a000cf1-943c-4979-b525-a1b700ab4c74201431022 ACTIVE
D/UseCaseAttachState(12733): Active and attached use case: [] for camera: 1
D/Camera2CameraImpl(12733): {Camera@c86a89f[id=1]} Use cases [androidx.camera.core.Preview-9e64dbef-b427-42a4-9edc-336238217282244191593, androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis-4a000cf1-943c-4979-b525-a1b700ab4c74201431022] now ATTACHED
D/UseCaseAttachState(12733): All use case: [androidx.camera.core.Preview-9e64dbef-b427-42a4-9edc-336238217282244191593, androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis-4a000cf1-943c-4979-b525-a1b700ab4c74201431022] for camera: 1
D/UseCaseAttachState(12733): Active and attached use case: [androidx.camera.core.Preview-9e64dbef-b427-42a4-9edc-336238217282244191593, androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis-4a000cf1-943c-4979-b525-a1b700ab4c74201431022] for camera: 1
D/Camera2CameraImpl(12733): {Camera@c86a89f[id=1]} Resetting Capture Session
D/Camera2CameraImpl(12733): {Camera@c86a89f[id=1]} Releasing session in state INITIALIZED
D/Camera2CameraImpl(12733): {Camera@c86a89f[id=1]} Attempting to force open the camera.
D/CameraStateRegistry(12733): tryOpenCamera(Camera@c86a89f[id=1]) [Available Cameras: 1, Already Open: false (Previous state: CLOSED)] --> SUCCESS
D/CameraStateRegistry(12733): Recalculating open cameras:
D/CameraStateRegistry(12733): Camera                                       State                 
D/CameraStateRegistry(12733): -------------------------------------------------------------------
D/CameraStateRegistry(12733): Camera@e206854[id=0]                         UNKNOWN               
D/CameraStateRegistry(12733): Camera@c86a89f[id=1]                         OPENING               
D/CameraStateRegistry(12733): -------------------------------------------------------------------
D/CameraStateRegistry(12733): Open count: 1 (Max allowed: 1)
D/Camera2CameraImpl(12733): {Camera@c86a89f[id=1]} Opening camera.
D/Camera2CameraImpl(12733): {Camera@c86a89f[id=1]} Transitioning camera internal state: INITIALIZED --> OPENING
D/CameraStateMachine(12733): New public camera state CameraState{type=OPENING, error=null} from OPENING and null
D/CameraStateMachine(12733): Publishing new public camera state CameraState{type=OPENING, error=null}
D/UseCaseAttachState(12733): All use case: [androidx.camera.core.Preview-9e64dbef-b427-42a4-9edc-336238217282244191593, androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis-4a000cf1-943c-4979-b525-a1b700ab4c74201431022] for camera: 1
E/IMGSRV  (12733): :4687: IsTextureConsistent: IMGEGLImage is not consistent
D/CameraManager(12733): Send Broadcast com.mediatek.camera.action.CAMERA_STATUS-1
D/Camera2CameraImpl(12733): {Camera@c86a89f[id=1]} Use case androidx.camera.core.Preview-9e64dbef-b427-42a4-9edc-336238217282244191593 ACTIVE
D/UseCaseAttachState(12733): Active and attached use case: [androidx.camera.core.Preview-9e64dbef-b427-42a4-9edc-336238217282244191593, androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis-4a000cf1-943c-4979-b525-a1b700ab4c74201431022] for camera: 1
D/Camera2CameraImpl(12733): {Camera@c86a89f[id=1]} Use case androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis-4a000cf1-943c-4979-b525-a1b700ab4c74201431022 ACTIVE
D/UseCaseAttachState(12733): Active and attached use case: [androidx.camera.core.Preview-9e64dbef-b427-42a4-9edc-336238217282244191593, androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis-4a000cf1-943c-4979-b525-a1b700ab4c74201431022] for camera: 1
D/Camera2CameraImpl(12733): {Camera@c86a89f[id=1]} CameraDevice.onOpened()
D/Camera2CameraImpl(12733): {Camera@c86a89f[id=1]} Transitioning camera internal state: OPENING --> OPENED
D/CameraStateRegistry(12733): Recalculating open cameras:
D/CameraStateRegistry(12733): Camera                                       State                 
D/CameraStateRegistry(12733): -------------------------------------------------------------------
D/CameraStateRegistry(12733): Camera@e206854[id=0]                         UNKNOWN               
D/CameraStateRegistry(12733): Camera@c86a89f[id=1]                         OPEN                  
D/CameraStateRegistry(12733): -------------------------------------------------------------------
D/CameraStateRegistry(12733): Open count: 1 (Max allowed: 1)
D/CameraStateMachine(12733): New public camera state CameraState{type=OPEN, error=null} from OPEN and null
D/CameraStateMachine(12733): Publishing new public camera state CameraState{type=OPEN, error=null}
D/UseCaseAttachState(12733): All use case: [androidx.camera.core.Preview-9e64dbef-b427-42a4-9edc-336238217282244191593, androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis-4a000cf1-943c-4979-b525-a1b700ab4c74201431022] for camera: 1
D/UseCaseAttachState(12733): Active and attached use case: [androidx.camera.core.Preview-9e64dbef-b427-42a4-9edc-336238217282244191593, androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis-4a000cf1-943c-4979-b525-a1b700ab4c74201431022] for camera: 1
D/SyncCaptureSessionBase(12733): [androidx.camera.camera2.internal.SynchronizedCaptureSessionBaseImpl@79ba54e] getSurface...done
D/CaptureSession(12733): Opening capture session.
D/DeferrableSurface(12733): use count+1, useCount=2 androidx.camera.core.SurfaceRequest$2@d3d84a1
D/DeferrableSurface(12733): New surface in use[total_surfaces=3, used_surfaces=2](androidx.camera.core.impl.ImmediateSurface@6e17952}
D/DeferrableSurface(12733): use count+1, useCount=1 androidx.camera.core.impl.ImmediateSurface@6e17952
I/BufferQueueProducer(12733): [SurfaceTexture-0-12733-4](id:31bd0000000c,api:4,p:805,c:12733) connect: api=4 producerControlledByApp=true
I/BufferQueueProducer(12733): [ImageReader-640x480f23m4-12733-4](id:31bd0000000d,api:4,p:805,c:12733) connect: api=4 producerControlledByApp=false
D/CaptureSession(12733): Attempting to send capture request onConfigured
D/CaptureSession(12733): Issuing request for session.
D/Camera2CaptureRequestBuilder(12733): createCaptureRequest
D/CaptureSession(12733): CameraCaptureSession.onConfigured() mState=OPENED
D/CaptureSession(12733): CameraCaptureSession.onReady() OPENED
D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore(12733): Storing event with priority=VERY_LOW, name=FIREBASE_ML_SDK for destination cct
D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler(12733): Upload for context TransportContext(cct, VERY_LOW, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MGNjL2xvZy9iYXRjaD9mb3JtYXQ9anNvbl9wcm90bzNc) is already scheduled. Returning...
D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore(12733): Storing event with priority=VERY_LOW, name=FIREBASE_ML_SDK for destination cct
D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler(12733): Upload for context TransportContext(cct, VERY_LOW, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MGNjL2xvZy9iYXRjaD9mb3JtYXQ9anNvbl9wcm90bzNc) is already scheduled. Returning...
D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore(12733): Storing event with priority=VERY_LOW, name=FIREBASE_ML_SDK for destination cct
D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler(12733): Upload for context TransportContext(cct, VERY_LOW, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MGNjL2xvZy9iYXRjaD9mb3JtYXQ9anNvbl9wcm90bzNc) is already scheduled. Returning...


did you set minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion in android/app/build.gradle?

@NipulRathod i have set min sdkversion to 21 & target sdkversion is showing as flutter.targetSdkVersion i am not sure whats that?

minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion are used to specify the minimum API level and target API level on which an Android app is designed to run.

@DineshFalwadiya remove flutter.targetSdkVersion and use 32 with targetSdkVersion and then check. It will work

@BobSmith let me check & i will let you know soon. Thanks for the suggestion.

@BobSmith I tried setting flutter.targetsdkversion to 34 but it still has the same issue.

Then you have to change code of camera for android 12

@BobSmith & how can i do that any idea pls?

@DineshFalwadiya Are you getting any exception or error if yes post that also and required code part to reproduce your problem. Consider checking https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/92973 it may help you.

I suggest you to stop camera + dispose controller insteadof just stop / start.
Also be sure to use latest version of the plugin.

@Eng tried your suggestion but no success :(

There is probably a reason why in the usage of package it asks you to add observer for the lifecycle. As you can see sometimes you need to restart or stop the scanner based on lifecycle state. I assume that in Android 12 it pauses after first scan and because you don't have the observer it doesn't restart when resumed.
Usage from their docs:
class MyState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  // ...

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    // If the controller is not ready, do not try to start or stop it.
    // Permission dialogs can trigger lifecycle changes before the controller is ready.
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return;
    }

    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
      case AppLifecycleState.hidden:
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        return;
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        // Restart the scanner when the app is resumed.
        // Don't forget to resume listening to the barcode events.
        _subscription = controller.barcodes.listen(_handleBarcode);

        unawaited(controller.start());
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        // Stop the scanner when the app is paused.
        // Also stop the barcode events subscription.
        unawaited(_subscription?.cancel());
        _subscription = null;
        unawaited(controller.stop());
    }
  }

  // ...
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  // Start listening to lifecycle changes.
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);

  // Start listening to the barcode events.
  _subscription = controller.barcodes.listen(_handleBarcode);

  // Finally, start the scanner itself.
  unawaited(controller.start());
}

@override
Future<void> dispose() async {
  // Stop listening to lifecycle changes.
  WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
  // Stop listening to the barcode events.
  unawaited(_subscription?.cancel());
  _subscription = null;
  // Dispose the widget itself.
  super.dispose();
  // Finally, dispose of the controller.
  await controller.dispose();
}

